# How can I get the month position with month name?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was wondering how I can get the month's position from a month's name.

I've tried using this below, but it would just come out as NaN.

```
var month = 'june';
var findMonth = new Date(month);

console.log(findMonth.getMonth());
```

What I want is to find the month's position, so like June is the 5th month. So I want it to come out as '5'.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by month's position?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to add that in. I just edited it in.

Comment: Couple of options could be to define your own mapping like { "Jan": 1 } and so on or use a library like momentjs

Comment: @Ipexidex725 June should be 6

Comment: `const monthIndex = ["January","February"....].indexOf("June"), monthNum = monthIndex+1`

Comment: How is `new Date(...)` supposed to know what *june* means? It also doesn't know what *June* or *Juni* or ... means. It's about representing dates, and as such you can pass in a datetime in milliseconds or a string representing a date in a specific format. Nothing else. There's no magic thing behind `new Date` that magically produces the result you expect.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it using `Date` you can slap on the day and year like this to get the value you want:

```js
let month = "june"
let monthDate = new Date(`${month} 01 2020`)
console.log(`${month} is the ${monthDate.getMonth()}th month in a zero based count of months`)
```

By adding the "01 2020" it becomes a date that the `Date` constructor can work with and every month has a first so it should always work.

Comment: `February is the 2th` month ;)

Comment: OP is expecting June to be 5th month, not 6th.  So dropping the `+1` is likely what they want.

Comment: I edited it to satisfy that and avoid saying "june is the 5th month" which is just wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `moment.js` which is a very popular library and will help you in the future in the app.

```
moment().month("July").format("M");
```

And if you want to get the Month name using `Date()` then you probably need the month names in an array and filter it. The class does not know the name of the months like `moment` library.

```
var d = new Date();
var month = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var n = month[d.getMonth()];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this by creating an array and find it through index

```
let months = ['january','feburary','march','april','may','june','july','august','september','october','november','december']
let month = 'june'
console.log( months.findIndexOf(month) + 1 + "th month")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `new Date()` expects a full date (M-D-Y), you can just specify an arbitrary day and year like say, `1, 2000` along with your month while creating the date object like this:

```js
var month = 'june';
var findMonth = new Date(month + " 1, 2000");

console.log(findMonth.getMonth());
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let months = ['january','feburary','march','april','may','june','july','august','september','october','november','december']
let month = 'june'

console.log( months.indexOf('march'));
```